# CQL: queries based on dates and times?

Tags: cassandra, cql

Suppose I have a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE events2 (
  homeid int,
  stamp timestamp,
  msec int,
  event int,
  sensor text,
  sequence int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((homeid), stamp, msec))
```

When I (attempt to) search based on dates / times I get:

```
cqlsh:nyce> select count(*) from events2 where homeid = 165 and stamp > "2014-10-26 00:00:00-0700";
Bad Request: line 1:60 no viable alternative at input '2014-10-26 00:00:00-0700'
```

Is there a way to make a query like this possible? Should I be  using **TimeUUID** instead?

Comment: try single quotes. I faced this issue couple of days ago so it might help?

Comment: I agree.  That query *should* work.  Replace the double quotes with single quotes, and retry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your query is the condition has to be an equality condition.

```
select count(*) from events2 where homeid = 165 and stamp >='2014-10-26 00:00:00-0700';
```

Returns:

```
 count
-------
     3
```

Correction, as Bryce says = is ok. It's the double quotation marks that are causing the problem. Just use single quotation marks:

```
select count(*) from events2 where homeid = 165 and stamp > '2014-10-26 00:00:00-0700';
```

Comment: I disagree.  If you read Patrick McFadin's post on TimeSeries data modeling, you'll see that greater/less-than queries on clustering columns (when the partitioning key is given) should work. http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/

Comment: Yes, I see that using = works: select count(*) from events2 where homeid = 165 and stamp ='2014-10-26 00:00:00-0700'; returns 1

Comment: Actually I was saying that using greater-than (instead of greater-than-or-equal-to) should still work.  The problem with using equals (=) on timestamp columns, is that timestamps are stored with a greater precision than the queried date.  That's where the MinTimeuuid and MaxTimeuuid functions (used with > or <) come into play.

Comment: Works. What does it mean by a 'viable alternative'?

Comment: It means 2014-10-26 00:00:00-0700 is not a useable value for stamp I guess: viable (practical) alternative (choice), not the best combination of words in this case.